# How Can I insert data in a table using an associative array?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, associative-array, insert-into

I've populate a associative array with information from a cursor and now I would like to insert associative array information into a table. How is it possible? Consider the associative array was created from a record.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

DECLARE
  TYPE rec_depts_info IS RECORD(
      v_dept_id   departments.department_id%TYPE,
      v_dept_name departments.department_name%TYPE);
  TYPE typ_depts_info IS TABLE OF rec_depts_info
      INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

  CURSOR cur_depts_info_1
  IS
     SELECT department_id, department_name
     FROM   departments
     WHERE  department_id   IS NOT NULL
     AND    department_name IS NOT NULL;

  t_depts_info_1 typ_depts_info;
  rec_depts_info_1 rec_depts_info;

  v_counter_1 PLS_INTEGER := 1;
  v_counter_2 PLS_INTEGER := 1;
BEGIN
  v_counter_1 := v_counter_1 + 1;

  FOR depts_info IN cur_depts_info_1
  LOOP
      t_depts_info_1(v_counter_1).v_dept_id   := depts_info.department_id;
      t_depts_info_1(v_counter_1).v_dept_name := depts_info.department_name;

      EXIT WHEN cur_depts_info_1%NOTFOUND;

  END LOOP;

  LOOP
    INSERT INTO tabla_pruebas
    VALUES(t_depts_info_1(v_counter_2).v_dept_id,
           t_depts_info_1(v_counter_2).v_dept_name)
    RETURNING column_1, column_2
    INTO      rec_depts_info_1.v_dept_id, rec_depts_info_1.v_dept_name;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DEPT ID: ' || rec_depts_info_1(v_counter_2).v_dept_id
                         || ' DEPT NAME: ' ||
                         rec_depts_info_1(v_counter_2).v_dept_name);

    v_counter_2 := v_counter_2 + 1;

    EXIT WHEN SQL%NOTFOUND;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

I'm trying to insert data into a new tabla using a simple LOOP but I received the following error:

```
Informe de error -
ORA-06550: line 51, column 41:
PLS-00222: no function with name 'REC_DEPTS_INFO_1' exists in this scope
ORA-06550: line 51, column 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: What is your interpretation of the PLS-0222 error?

Comment: You trying to use record as an array here `rec_depts_info_1(v_counter_2).v_dept_id`. Options: use proper array `t_depts_info_1(v_counter_2).v_dept_id` or record `rec_depts_info_1.v_dept_id`

Comment: Thanks but now I received "NO DATA FOUND" error.

Comment: It's result of `v_counter_1` starts with 2 while second counter starts with 1. Why you incrementing `v_counter_1` outside the loop?

Comment: Better use bulk operations (select and insert) for indexed tables. And what is the real aim of that block of code?

Comment: I didn't know about BULK COLLECT. Now I'm reading about it. Thanks for your help sir.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of your explicit loop, you can use [the `FORALL` bulk syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/forall_statement.htm#LNPLS01321) to insert all your array values at once:

```
  FORALL i IN t_depts_info_1.first..t_depts_info_1.last
    INSERT INTO tabla_pruebas
    VALUES(t_depts_info_1(i).v_dept_id,
           t_depts_info_1(i).v_dept_name);
```

[Read more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/tuning.htm#LNPLS01205) about `FORALL` and other bulk query and binding topics. Using `BULK COLLECT` as well to populate your array, you can simplify your code to:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE rec_depts_info IS RECORD(
      v_dept_id   departments.department_id%TYPE,
      v_dept_name departments.department_name%TYPE);
  TYPE typ_depts_info IS TABLE OF rec_depts_info
      INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

  t_depts_info_1 typ_depts_info;
BEGIN
  SELECT department_id, department_name
  BULK COLLECT INTO t_depts_info_1
  FROM   departments
  WHERE  department_id   IS NOT NULL
  AND    department_name IS NOT NULL;

  FORALL i IN t_depts_info_1.first..t_depts_info_1.last
    INSERT INTO tabla_pruebas
    VALUES(t_depts_info_1(i).v_dept_id,
           t_depts_info_1(i).v_dept_name);
END;
/
```

Although with this contrived example you don't need the collection or any PL/SQL at all, you can do a simple `insert...select`:

```
INSERT INTO tabla_pruebas (column_1, column_2)
SELECT department_id, department_name
FROM   departments
WHERE  department_id   IS NOT NULL
AND    department_name IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: I understood!! Thanks alot for your help. I need to practice more PLSQL!!! It's very helpful. Thanks again!!!